# Import error on Google colab after pip install and restarting runtime

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn, pip, google-colaboratory

I want to use a package (resreg) on Google Colab. I install it in my first cell

```
!pip install resreg
```

I get the following output:

```
Collecting resreg
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/74/0b664a8507e15507da5031fd92877d57551a7d362edc8089aa369c340e84/resreg-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting scikit-learn==0.21.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/6c/ec121123c671d980c6969dfc69d0f09e1d7f88d80d373f511e61d773b85c/scikit_learn-0.21.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (6.6MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 6.6MB 3.8MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from resreg) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.24.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from resreg) (1.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from resreg) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn==0.21.0->resreg) (0.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pandas>=0.24.0->resreg) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pandas>=0.24.0->resreg) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas>=0.24.0->resreg) (1.12.0)
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn, resreg
  Found existing installation: scikit-learn 0.22.2.post1
    Uninstalling scikit-learn-0.22.2.post1:
      Successfully uninstalled scikit-learn-0.22.2.post1
Successfully installed resreg-0.1 scikit-learn-0.21.0
```

Then I restart the runtime using
`">Runtime >Restart Runtime"`

When I try to import the package, I get the following error

```py
from sklearn.linear_models import ElasticNet
import resreg
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-be63596e9fde> in <module>()
     1 from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet
---> 2 import resreg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resreg'
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in different code cells:

[1]

```
!git clone https://github.com/jafetgado/resreg.git
!cd resreg
```

[2]

```
!pip install -e resreg
```

[3]

```
import resreg
# ... Rest of your code goes here.
```

If it doesn't work on the first time try to restart the kernel (go to Runtime -> Restart runtime) before running [3].

One particular thing that's worth noticing when installing resreg is that as it is noted on the stacktrace it is dependent of [scikit-learn-0.21.0](https://scikit-learn.org/0.21/), and therefore you won't be able to use the new features available on the [newest stable release](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) (currently 23.0) and it's new features.

```
 Installing collected packages: scikit-learn, resreg
  Found existing installation: scikit-learn 0.22.2.post1
    Uninstalling scikit-learn-0.22.2.post1:
      Successfully uninstalled scikit-learn-0.22.2.post1
  Running setup.py develop for resreg
Successfully installed resreg scikit-learn-0.21.0
```